# Google Optimize: "Calculated Conversion Rate" contradicting "Probability to be Best"

Tags: google-analytics, reporting, ab-testing, google-optimize, abtest

I'm seeing some strange things on a currently running experiment.

[image: Google optimize reporting]

- The Observed Conversion Rate is noticeably higher on the Original,
  however Optimize's analysis is that the variant is more likely to be
  best. What should I trust here?
- The Modeled Conversion Rate seems
  also way off, with a median CR of 1.2% (original) and 1.3% (variant).
  Why would the model overshoot reality so much?

Thanks for your guidance!

Comment: This doesn't explain the results, but I had always believed Google (and other results that look like this with probability to be best) are based on a Bayesian stats. If you punch in your numbers on https://abtestguide.com/bayesian/, you find that "New Service Enabled" has only a 12% chance of being best, aligned with your intuition.  I'm not sure what else Google is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: Exactly! And as always Google's model is a black box..